# Javascript keyup call other table value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, keyup

I have a table like this:

```
<tbody id="invoice_item">  
<tr>   
<td><input name='qty[]' type='text' class='form-control form-control-sm qty' value='0'></td>
        <td><input name='price[]' type='text' class='form-control form-control-sm price' value='0'></td>
        <td><input name='sub_total[]' type='text' class='form-control form-control-sm sub_total' value='0' readonly></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to make Javascript when qty/price change subtotal changed too.
My js:

```
 $("#invoice_item").delegate(".qty","keyup",function(){
    var qty = $(this).val();
    var price = tr.find(".price").val();
    alert(price);
    var sub_total = qty * price;
    alert(sub_total);
    tr.find(".sub_total").html(sub_total);


    })
    $("#invoice_item").delegate(".price","keyup",function(){
      var price = $(this).val();
      var qty = tr.find(".qty").val();
      alert(qty);

      })
```

It seems the trouble is `tr.find(".").val();`.
I try to alert it, but no use.. anyone can help? How I can call the other input?
`$(this).val();` is no problem.

Comment: Please provide more context: what is the `invoice_item` element? Add it to your HTML code. Also add your definition of `tr` variable to the JS code.

Comment: Thanks for the editing, but still we can't see where and how `tr` variable is defined.

Comment: If it's not defined at all, so that's the reason why your `alert(price)` call doesn't happen.

Comment: @DmitryDruganov yes its not defined, how to define the tr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it,
i must define it by 
var tr = $(this).parent().parent();

thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

`delegate()` is deprecated in v 3.0. Which jquery are you using?

You can attach the events to the input tags themselves using the new `on` method, like so:

```
$(".qty").on("keyup",function(){}
```

To get the other input value you can use this:

```
$(".price").val()
```

Comment: still not working.. i use <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: what if i got more than 1 row in table with same name in array?